# Easier to put $_POST With Array

Tags: php, arrays, post, key-value, strip-tags

I did try many times to make values easier to put. It's my meaning to put values with array, because I don't need to type more values then, he can put it automatically.. For example, I write:

```
<?php

$Value1 = array (
             'Somevalue1' => 'SomeValue2',
             'SomeValue1' => 'SomeValue2',
             'SomeValue1' => 'SomeValue2',
             );

// This is method what i want to put in, but i dont think that its right
$Value1[0] = strip_tags($_POST['.Value1[0].']);

// Its the meaning that he put so out:

$SomeValue1 = strip_tags($_POST['SomeValue2']);
$SomeValue1 = strip_tags($_POST['SomeValue2']);
$SomeValue1 = strip_tags($_POST['SomeValue2']);

?>
```

I don't have to much experience with array, I am just learning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is this what you want to do:

```
// create an array with key = field-name in form
$val = array(
    'name' => null, 
    'lastname' => null, 
    'date_of_birth' => null, 
    'favorite_color' => null);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // form has been sent

    // retrieve values from $_POST and store it in $val
    foreach ($val as $key => $value)
        $val[$key] = $_POST[$key];

    // show the result
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($val);
    echo "</pre>";

} // if isset
```

see live demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/j03DtO

Comment: Hi michi, yess thats what i was looking.. Thank you very much for sharing, but if you dont mind, i just have one question.. how can you add strip_tags to secure $_POST in this kind of coding? Thanks

Comment: @DavySays use 'PDO' and let it take care of escaping your data. search for PDO and mysql

Comment: Ok, i will search for that. Thank you very much for your help and your code, if im right, i did push on green button for your answer.

Comment: @DavySays yes, you accepted my answer, thank you very much! Have fun coding!